# Replacing variable names in string with actual variables

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace variable names in a string with the actual variables. The string would look like this:

> Hello $person->fullname$
>   Your login-ID is $person->id and your password is $person->password

The code should then replace the stuff after $ with the actual variables, i.e.

```
$string = 'Hello'. $person->fullname .'\nYour login-ID is'. $person->id .'and your password is'. $person->password
```

This would mean replacing a $person->id with

> '. $person->id .'

I guess I should use preg_replace, but I have no idea how I can make sure to match anything between $ and the next space character. What do I have to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
$a = 'Hello $person->fullname Your login-ID is $person->id and your password is $person->password';
$words = explode(' ',$a);
$output = "";
foreach($words as $word){
    if($word[0] == '$'){
        $word = "'.".$word.".'";
    }
    $output = $output.$word." ";
}
```

The $output string will be `"Hello '.$person->fullname.' Your login-ID is '.$person->id.' and your password is '.$person->password.' "`